# How to build a search with new features?

Tags: search-engine

I want to build a search engine for my project this year, so what I
need to implement in my project to get best grade (I need new ideas
for search for video or audio...). How and where can I start to learn
about this topic. I want to use Java and any framework on it. I know
that I can't build a Google Search, but I need to implement a new idea
in my project to get best grade.

Comment: Can you tell us what technology you already know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you start with an open source search engine like Lucene ([Java](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)) and start adding features on top of the plaform. Perhaps you could build a plugin for searching camera meta data (I.E., EXIF)?

PS. You might want to start marking the correct answers for the 20 questions you've already asked. Having an acceptance rate of 21% doesn't really give the recognition to those who work hard to answer your questions.

Comment: thanks about your advice , but this because i dont know that i should accept answers .